# How to filter results from SQLite database before displaying in Array List?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am having trouble figuring out how to filter out specific results from the SQLite DB before the results are displayed in the list view. Not seen are the values which contain the present dates, and I want to know how to make it so if the retrieved month and year don't equal the values I set before, that they won't be visible.

The 2 values that have the current dates set to them are currentMonth and currentYear. (not displayed in the code below).

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> dates =  dbTools.getAllContacts();

    final ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter( NameOfClass.this, dates, R.layout.exp_item_entry,
            new String[] {"month", "year"},
            new int[] {R.id.MonthTextView, R.id.YearTextView});

    setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Why don't you write a query itself to get filtered data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **easy** answer would be: use a `WHERE` clause in a rawQuery.

The **real** answer is: it actually depends on the filter you want.
You might use `Like`s, `JOIN`s, `aggregation functions`, `WHERE`, `GROUP BY`, `HAVING`, ... or any combination of these.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a BaseAdapter and modify the information and after call the notifyDataSetChanged to refresh the ListView.

```
class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> dates;

    public MyAdapter(LayoutInflater inflater, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> dates){
        this.inflater = inflater;
        this.dates = dates;
        }

    public void setDates(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> dates) {
        this.dates = dates;
        }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return dates.size();
        }

    @Override
    public HashMap<String, String> getItem(int i) {
        return dates.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        //Definition of your views to use.
        TextView monthTextView = null;
        TextView yearTextView = null;
        if(view == null) {
            //Inflate the item.
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.exp_item_entry, null);
            //Your findViewById to link the views
            monthTextView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.monthTextView);
            yearTextView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.yearTextView);
            }
        //What you wanna do with the views linked up.
        HashMap<String, String> item = getItem(i);
        monthTextView.setText(item.get("month"));
        yearTextView.setText(item.get("year"));
        return view;
    }
```

To use the adapter in our ListView:

```
MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(getLayoutInflater(), dates);
...
listView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

And to update the information, you can perform a rawQuery using WHERE to filter the information and you only need put the filtered dates in the adapter and call notifyDataSetChanged.

myAdapter.setDates(filteredDates);
   myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: Wow thank you for that in-depth response! But I just have found success with the simple change of adding WHERE to the query in the database class.